# Is default font-size adapted for device?

Tags: css, font-size, typography

I wonder, is default font-size adapted for device? I mean it should, right?

**If it is adapted**, why we need to add media-query for changing font-size, like this:

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
    @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
    @media (max-width: @screen-md-min) {
        font-size: 93%;
    }
    @media (max-width: @screen-sm-min) {
        font-size: 87%; 
    }
    @media (max-width: @screen-xs-min) {
        font-size: 81%; 
    }
}
p {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Code above only do worst, right? (It will create too small text)

In this case this should work perfect (yes, so simple):

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}
p {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Of course by changing browser width on desktop we will not see font-size changing effect. But do we need to see it?

I think, that this media-query could be useful for testing on desktop only, but should be removed from real application.

Am I wrong?

(Hope to hear from guru css :)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) you might want to read about em and rem. Your first box of code logically makes sense, but it isn't how rem or em work. Your second box of code is correct. In the case of rem the font size on different devices is determined by the percent declared in the CSS for HTML.

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, it will adapted based off of the percent declared in the CSS for HTML. I would refer to the article above for the details on how this works between em and rem.
2. You don't need media queries for this.
3. Media queries can be used to adjust the font-size, em or rem, based on device if your em or rem doesn't render the way you want your font-size to look. They aren't just for testing. They are actually really important.

As the article mentions I would also have your font-size set in pixels for older browsers to fall back onto.

Comment: @scabbiaza if this answer is appropriate for your question it would be greatly appreciated if you could mark the question as answered and my answer as correct.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Of course media queries are important, i mentioned "for testing" only this particular queries that i wrote above. As I see all modern browser [support rem](http://caniuse.com/rem), so I think we could do it without fallback now. Could you please explain, what do you mean about "Your first box of code logically makes sense, but it isn't how rem or em work."?

Comment: Max, before close I would like to hear from other devs as well.

Comment: @scabbiaza Nice little resource there. When I said that I was trying to tell you that why you or someone would do that makes sense, but at the same time that isn't how rem or em is suppose to be handled. Because they expect to receive a percent as apart of their resizing method in order to adjust the font-sizes on the page according to the device. That first box is essentially overkill.